# How do I align my DocumentFragment in the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a set of buttons 9x9 but they are in the left upper corner and I would like to align them all in the center. I have tried using `<div>` to align it all, but it doesn't work and nothing appears on the page.

```
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i < 9 ; i++){ 
        var row = document.createElement("tr") 
        for (var j=0; j < 9 ; j++){ 
                var elem = document.createElement('input');
                elem.className = 'gumb';
                elem.type = 'button';
                ...something...
                docFrag.appendChild(elem); 
            } 
        document.body.appendChild(docFrag); 
        document.body.appendChild(row); 
    }
```

Comment: what are your `gumb` class fields in css?

Comment: A `DocumentFragment` is not a `DocumentFragment` once it is appended to the DOM. It's just the elements appended within as individual elements.

Comment: @AlirezaHI `<style>
.gumb {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.gumb: focus {
background-color: red;
}


</style> `

Comment: @HereticMonkey so what does that mean for me?

Comment: In means that, if you've been appending `input`s individually to your `DocumentFragment`, they won't be wrapped in any kind of wrapping element; it's as if you just plopped a bunch of `input`s into your `body` element. Likewise with your `tr`s, which doesn't make any sense, since those tags must be children of `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, or `tfoot` tags.

Comment: @HereticMonkey does that mean I can't align them individually nor as a whole as long as they are defined using `DocumentFragment` ? Should I rated try to make the buttons in a table or somehow?

Comment: I mean, I would probably put them in a wrapper and use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) to lay them out in a nice grid. Not to toot my own horn, but that's what I did on my own site for a "minesweeper" clone: https://heretic-monkey.link/mynsweepr-tres/build/ :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's nice. Did you write it all in js or django or? I'm trying to make minesweeper myself.

Comment: That one's written all in JS, using React and Redux. The code's all available on GitHub if you're curious: https://github.com/mikemccaughan/heretic-monkey.link/tree/master/mynsweepr-tres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this js instead:

```js
// use div to add class to center the elements
var item = document.createElement('div');
item.className = "container";

    for (var i=0; i < 9 ; i++){
        var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var row = document.createElement("br") 
        for (var j=0; j < 9 ; j++){ 
                var elem = document.createElement('input');
                elem.className = 'gumb';
                elem.type = 'button';
                docFrag.appendChild(elem); 
            } 
        item.appendChild(docFrag); 
        item.appendChild(row); 
    } 
document.body.appendChild(item)
```

```css
// make the `container` div full width and center the items in it
.container {
     width: 100%;
     text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This only puts all my buttons in one row 1x81 :/

Comment: @klopa I change the solution. Try this one.

Comment: Adding explanation of code usually results in more upvotes than downvotes...

Comment: @HereticMonkey tnx for your comment. I added some comment to explain the solution.